# Searching through Excel Data

Tags: python, excel

Essentially I want it to query an excel dataset. I have a list of names in excel, I want python to ask me a name and receive an input. Then I want it to scour the excel sheet and return
"I know you" if the name is in the list
or "We have never met" if its not

I'm struggling with the loop as I get a print value for each excel sheet, where as I only want one result from the whole search.

Here's my code

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('namelist.xlsx')

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

print('What is your name?')
name = input()

for row_index in range(2,sheet.get_highest_row()):

 if sheet.cell(row=row_index,column=1).value == name:        
 print('I know you')
 exit()

else:

 print('We have never met')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your loop iterates through every row and prints either two values (*I know you* or *We have never met*) for each cell and will only exit on successfully finding the `name`.

Consider moving the print statements outside the loop to output only once on a conditional statement.

```
found = False
for row_index in range(2,sheet.get_highest_row()):    
    if sheet.cell(row=row_index,column=1).value == name:        
        found = True

if found = True:
    print('I know you')
else:
    print('We have never met')
```